# ffmpeg says "no such file/directory"

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -s 320x240 -aspect 320: 240 -r 30 -an output.roq
```

I am trying to convert to roq so I can watch on my calculator, but it says "no such file/directory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it said `no such file/directory` I'd hazard a guess that `myvideo.avi` was *not* in the directory that you initiated the command from.

You might also consider prefacing both files with `./` eg `./myvideo.avi`, and `./output.roq`

Comment: Hi I put the video file called myvideo.avi in the same directory as the bin folder

Comment: @supergamer4238 You should not put the video in the same folder as the `bin` folder (whatever that is). The video must be in the same folder where your shell is currently at (run `pwd` to see where that is). Or you use the correct path to the video. Please go through a basic tutorial on how to use a shell.

Comment: Hi thanks it works now but, thank you so much!!! May I ask if it is possible to create a batch file so I can just drop the video on the batch file to make it easy ?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the space between ':' and '240' in `-aspect 320: 240` as thats causing the error.

Although this does not address the OP's original error, removing the space in the aspect option will fix the next error:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -s 320x240 -aspect 320:240 -r 30 -an output.roq
```

Comment: @mwjb, please include correct version of entire command line instead of the portion you have shown with the answer,, it may encourage readers to Down Vote the post as well as OP can't utilize it too!